# Media Library is not showing + some plugin's favicons in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, cpanel, database-migration

Several days ago I added a SSL certificate to my website which is hosted by goDaddy and managed by WordPress. The SSL is working fine but Images on Media Library are not showing as well as some of the plugin's favicons - [See Image](http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/qsvh8cu8n1p5do770uuh0g7536_screenshot-savinaradeva.com-2019.02.07-14-55-47.png)

**What I've already tried:**

- I've changed WP and Site addresses in Settings-> General to go to https
- I set the path in Settings->Media - 'Store uploads in this folder' to go to /wp-content/uploads/
- I've tried 'Really Simple SSL', 'SSL Insecure Content Fixer', 'Redirection' plugins as well as 'Better Search Replace' plugin where I've replaced all http to go to https
- I've troubleshooted the website with 'Health Check & Troubleshooting' plugin and images were still not showing
- I've add these lines to my wp-config.php

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

and this line before require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );
```

- I've added these lines to my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

- I've chenged the permession on 'wp-content' and 'uploads' directories to 755, then to 777 and still not working
- I've contacted my hosting provider and ask them to update my php database
- I've checked how much space left on the server and I have enough
- When I inspect the homepage and I have the following errors :

```
GET https://savinaradeva.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/cropped-favicon-32x32.jpeg 404 (Not Found)
```

and then when I open the link in a new tab it goes to 'Page cannot be found' BUT when I check the path on the server and open wp-content/uploads/2019/01/cropped-favicon-32x32.jpeg - the images are there. I've tried to copy the path and open it in a browser but it goes to 404 page.

I don't have any problems to upload images to the gallery - the file is there, it is pointing https but images are still not showing. If I download an image from Media Library in Wordpress - it goes broken BUT if I download an image from the server - It is ok. Also, the favicons of the site seems to be on place.

I guess it is something wrong with the PATH but I'm open for ideas and suggestion what should I try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your htaccess file with the below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yourwebsite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourwebsite/$1  [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```